# Should I accept a "thank you" edit?

Tags: discussion

An anonymous user made the following edit to the answer I gave to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/430474/use-sudo-command-for-script-ssh-server)

[The edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/11769) is merely a "thank you" note.  So it doesn't seem to be a "valid" edit and more something that should have been added as a comment.

The [user who asked the question](https://superuser.com/users/137048/vicky) has a rep of 1 now and thus can't add comments I believe, which might be why she opted for an edit.

However rejecting the edit might appear impolite or ungrateful.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Do note that in some cases even users with 1 rep can add comments as explained in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation). It's a tiny footnote at the end of the privileges table, but it's there. So I think there's no escuse for a "thank you" edit.

Comment: @devius The edit would be attributed to the unregistered user. It looks like she trashed her browser cookies, or changed the browser.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Such edits should be rejected. The edit adds nothing but noise to the answer; I don't believe it's impolite.

Comment: You should however leave a comment letting him know that the appropriate way to say "this worked" is to click the checkmark.

Comment: Looks like `[x] invalid edit` to me.

Answer (score 6):

I certainly would not accept such an edit.  If we're supposed to [*remove* this sort of content from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), why should we approve edits that *add* such meaningless content?